# Magento 2.4.6 calling createOrder() causes exception with elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, exception, json, create-order

In one of my scripts, calling createOrder() ( from vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php ) causes an exception:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;"},"status":400}
```

I'm very confused at these results. Any thoughts?

The rest of the exception text:

```
#0 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Connections/Connection.php(328): OpenSearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError()
#1 /vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(28): OpenSearch\Connections\Connection->OpenSearch\Connections\{closure}()
#2 /vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(65): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then()
#3 /vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then()
#4 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Connections/Connection.php(340): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Core::proxy()
#5 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Connections/Connection.php(238): OpenSearch\Connections\Connection->OpenSearch\Connections\{closure}()
#6 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Transport.php(113): OpenSearch\Connections\Connection->performRequest()
#7 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Client.php(1389): OpenSearch\Transport->performRequest()
#8 /vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Client.php(210): OpenSearch\Client->performRequest()
#9 /vendor/magento/module-open-search/Model/SearchClient.php(172): OpenSearch\Client->bulk()
#10 /vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/Elasticsearch.php(312): Magento\OpenSearch\Model\SearchClient->bulkQuery()
#11 /vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Indexer/IndexerHandler.php(186): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch->deleteDocs()
#12 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(220): Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler->deleteIndex()
#13 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(198): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->processBatch()
#14 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(152): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeByDimensions()
#15 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(250): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->execute()
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeList()
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callParent()
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#19 /generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#20 /vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(533): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->executeList()
#21 /vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(294): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexList()
#22 /vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(299): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexList()
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/AbstractProcessor.php(69): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexList()
#24 /vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/ReindexQuoteInventoryObserver.php(84): Magento\Framework\Indexer\AbstractProcessor->reindexList()
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\ReindexQuoteInventoryObserver->execute()
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#28 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
#29 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(630): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch()
#30 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(500): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote()
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit()
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent()
#33 /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Plugin/CouponUsagesIncrement.php(54): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#34 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\SalesRule\Plugin\CouponUsagesIncrement->aroundSubmit()
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#36 /generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#37 /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php(2012): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->submit()
#38 /app/code/Bcse/Migration/Model/OrdersProcessor.php(601): Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create->createOrder()
```